# Trying to access configured const across express router files

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to node js so this might be a simple question. In my `index.js` file I have configured an imported module `admin`, and I wish to use this configuration across my routed files. How do I pass/access this configured constant? I don't want to have to configure it in every single file.

```
// In index.js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require("express")
const myApi = require("./api/my")
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const app = express();
app.use("/api/my", myApi.myRouter);


// In ./api/my/index.js
const myRouter = express.Router();
myRouter.get('/account', function(req, res) {
    admin.auth().... <- Need to use the previously configured admin here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a top level middleware to define `admin` property inside the `req` object:

```
app.use( function (req, res, next) {
    req.admin = admin;
    next();
});
```

Now the fireBase instance is available in any route handler via `req.admin`

Another approach consist of passing the `admin` const when you requiring the router file:

index.js:

```
const myApi = require("./api/my")(admin)
```

Router file:

```
const myRouter = express.Router();

module.exports = function (admin) {

    myRouter.get('/account', function(req, res) {
        admin.auth().... 
    }

    return myRouter;

}
```

Another way is to use [app.set()](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.set) to store a reference to the `admin` object and [app.get()](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.get) to get that reference:

index.js

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
app.set('admin', admin);
```

Router file:

```
myRouter.get('/account', function(req, res) {
    const admin = req.app.get('admin');
    admin.auth().... 
}
```

Comment: I actually went with creating a new js file, initialised admin in there and exported it to the module, that way I could import it whenever I wanted. However these ways are also good alternatives! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it global .

**global.admin = require('firebase-admin');**

This can be used across routed files .
But I recommend you to import in every file because global declaration clutter up the global namespace and are slower to look up than local variables.